# Glance widget actionStartActivity not working properly

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, glance-appwidget, glance

I am trying to implement a glance widget and start an activity while clicking on a button. But it seems like it's not working properly for me. This is my code:

```
 DistributionDateView(context, deliveryDates, postalCode) {
                println("it should work i think")
                actionStartActivity(AddParcelManuallyActivity.newIntent(context = context))
                actionStartActivity<AddParcelManuallyActivity>()
                actionStartActivity(AddParcelManuallyActivity::class.java)
}
```

Where DistributionDateView has a onclick.
I have tried 3 different ways, "it should work I think" is printing in the logs... but nothing is happening.
What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`actionStartActivity` is just return a object of interface `StartActivityAction`. It should be used in some glance function. It is not an alternative of `context.startActivity` which is a function.

```kotlin
//source code in package androidx.glance
fun GlanceModifier.clickable(onClick: Action): GlanceModifier =
    this.then(ActionModifier(onClick))

//source code in package androidx.glance
@Composable
fun Button(
    text: String,
    onClick: Action,
    modifier: GlanceModifier = GlanceModifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    style: TextStyle? = null,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
)
```

and one example is

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyContent() {
    Image(
        provider = provider,
        modifier = GlanceModifier
            .clickable(actionStartActivity<MainActivity>()),
        contentDescription = ""
    )
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Same Issue here (using androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.0.0-beta01).
My Workaround is starting Activity the usual way:

```
            Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java).apply{
            flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(this)
        }
```

Important is the use of "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" cause you are calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity

Comment: Still happen on 1.0.0-rc01

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77042028/5376678 should be the accepted answer. Please upvote that instead.